# Reactive Programming -- Respond to a Sequence of Events

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.reactive

I'm trying to use Reactive Extensions for Unity ([UniRX](https://github.com/neuecc/UniRx), a reimplementation of Reactive Extensions that is compatible with Unity 4.5) for gesture recognition.  There's a [simple example out there](http://blog.zuehlke.com/en/gesture-recognition-with-leap-motion-controller-and-reactive-extensions/), but it uses a really simple gesture.

I've written logic to generate a stream of feature vectors in an IObservable.

I'd like to implement logic that looks like  "Look at an IObservable. When (initial conditions occur), unless (cancel/abort conditions), emit a gesture event after (complete conditions occur)."

I can write RX expressions for each set of conditions, but chaining them together such that they function in this way isn't obvious to me.

ie:

```
// initial condition -- passes events through if hand more open than some threshold, and closing
handStream
    .Buffer(2, 1)
    .Where(h => h[0].pinchStrength > m_openThresh)
    .Where(h => h[0].pinchStrength > h[1].pinchStrength)
```

or

```
// end condition -- passes event through if hand more closed than some threshold
handStream
    .Where(h => h[0].pinchStrength < m_pinchThresh)
```

but the second expression doesn't make sense unless the first conditions have been met at some previous time.

How should I approach this, paradigmatically?

Comment: Reminds me of [Rxx parsers](https://rxx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Parsers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need to do some sort of variation on the following query:

```
var query =
    handStream
        .Buffer(2, 1)
        .Publish(bhs =>
            bhs
                .Where(h => /* start condition */)
                .Select(h =>
                    bhs
                        .Where(x => /* values to return */)
                        .TakeUntil(
                            bhs
                                .Where(x => /* stop condition */))))
        .Switch();
```

This basically looks for your start condition and then return an observable that will return the values you're interested in until the stop condition occurs. The `.Switch()` method "switches" to the last observable returned (closing the previous one). It worth playing with this operator as it is very powerful.

You may or may not need the `.Publish(...)` operator depending on your initial stream.